# Using python3 to fill online text field

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to use Python to enter data into two text fields in this site:

http:
//
59
.
145
.
203
.
105/
I have successfully done that using selenium webdriver with PhantomJS, but I really want to use urllib request to do this....as I want to port this program to SL4A as a python script on Android.... Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Look at these:

 - [Using Python Requests to Select Forms][1]
 - [Python urllib2 automatic form filling and retrieval of results][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507169/using-python-requests-to-select-forms
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667699/python-urllib2-automatic-form-filling-and-retrieval-of-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple form with submit method POST. You need to fill the `data` argument to `urlopen`, after encoding it with `urlencode`.

Something like:

```
data = urlencode({'txtRoll': N, 'txtEnroll': M})
...urlopen(url, data=data)
```

With N the "Roll number" and M the "Registration number".

Comment: The problem is when and only when the button is clicked a javascript runs in the background to enter the data anyway I can get around that

Comment: How do I use urllib to initiate the formSubmit() method

Comment: @user3673209, what do you mean? If you submit using Python + urllib, javascript doesn't play into it at all.

Comment: I tried that but the response I get is always of the same page....This is the code that I am using is: https://github.com/CyberChild/openCV/blob/master/stack_overflow.py

Comment: @user3673209: Oh, there's a hidden field that must be filled as well. Add `'txhSubmit' : 'Submit'` to the data dictionary.

Comment: THANKS A LOT MAN.....YOU TRULY ARE A LIFESAVER!!!!!!!!!

Comment: There just seems to be one little problem....although I am getting the response I only get the default html...the upper part of the html which displays all the grades and stuff are gone